# Can I Update Meteor Underscore package?

Tags: meteor

Meteor uses a very dated 1.5.2 version of Underscore.  Two years old this Sept and missing a lot of great stuff that is in the current 1.8.2 library.

Can the package be updated?

Comment: If you're looking for specific additional underscore functionality there are a number of on atmospherejs.com: see https://atmospherejs.com/?q=underscore

Comment: I was justing looking to able to use the current underscore helpers like findIndex (and a bunch of others added since Meteors old version).

Comment: for instance `mapObject()` method is not available in my meteor 1.0

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can update the version used in your app, though not the version used by Meteor itself. See this [GitHub issue](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/issues/1009).

The easiest solution is to just replace Underscore with Lodash, which has even more features than the latest Underscore. Per [this thread](https://forums.meteor.com/t/underscore-lodash/666/2), it’s this easy:

```
meteor add alethes:lodash
```

And in your startup code:

```
// Use lodash instead of underscore
_ = lodash;
```

If you prefer the latest Underscore instead of Lodash, it looks like at the moment you’ll need to download the file from [underscorejs.org](http://underscorejs.org/) and save it into either your `lib` or `client/compatibility` folder. It should execute after Meteor’s libraries themselves load, and hijack the `_` variable. You can also initialize it with `_.noConflict()`, in which case you can let `_` stay with Meteor’s version and you can assign the new Underscore to something else, e.g. `underscore = _.noConflict();`.

I should probably mention that either of these solutions will leave you with both libraries (Meteor’s old version of Underscore, and the new library you’re using instead) downloading to the client. Until Meteor itself upgrades (see GitHub issue above), that is unavoidable.

Comment: thank you!  I was hoping to avoid the duplicate libraries.  I will definitely use lodash if I'm going to have to incur the extra 'weight' of another library.

Answer (score 2):

My solution using lodash with Meteor ES2015:

`meteor npm i lodash --save`

and import lodash **/imports/startup/client/index.js**:

`import lodash from 'lodash';
window._ = lodash;`

Regards, Nicholls

Comment: npm package is a solid way to go, usually updated much quicker than a meteor package that wraps an npm pkg